# how i can remove border radius from below the image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I delete the card's border radius from below the image?
I want to delete the border with an arrow in the attached image, While maintaining the border of the image on both sides

[image]

```dart
ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "Cart",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    AppImageAssets.producttestimage))),
                        Expanded(
                            flex: 3,
                            child: ListTile(title: Text("macbook pro games"))),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                          children: [],
                        ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

I'm a beginner and I don't know what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can wrap your `Image.asset` in a `ClipRRect` Widget like this:

```
           ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(AppImageAssets.producttestimage),
```

Or you can use the `shape` property of the `Card` to be applied to the whole Card Widget like this:

```
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
            topRight: Radius.circular(12),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
          ),
        ),
```

You don't need to use a `Container` widget if you're using a `Card` widget, they're pretty much the same. If you prefer to use a Container instead of Card, you can have better design controls by adding borders and shadows and control the curve on the edges with the `borderRadius` property. for example:

```
 Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
   child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
            topRight: Radius.circular(12),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
          ),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey, // You can adjust the border color
            width: 1.0, // You can adjust the border width
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(...),
```